# How to connect two command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, apache-commons, args

I need to connect two command line arguments. The user is supposed to put `-input` "filename.txt" and/or `-output` "filename.txt" but I can't seem connect the `-input` or `-output` parts with the filename.

So for example the user could enter any of the following:

```
java classname
java classname -input filename.txt
java classname -output filename.txt
java classname -input filename.txt -output filename.txt
java classname -output filename.txt -input filename.txt
```

I tried this:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if(args[i].equals("-input")){
            input = args[i + 1];
        }
        else{
            //input from terminal
        }

        if(args[i].equals("-output")){
            output = args[i + 1];
        }
        else{
            //output to terminal
        }
```

But it's not working and seems inelegant. I have been looking into the Apache Commons CLI but I can't seem to quite figure out how that works and if there is a applicable function. Using the Apache thing or some other way is there some way I can connect the -input to the filename.txt?

Comment: "-fin" and "-input" are completely different Strings, and likewise for "-fout" and "-output". Why make things more confusing for you and us?

Comment: Oops! sorry, I copied my commented code and didn't realize I hadn't changed the String to match. I fixed it now.

Comment: If your command line structure is correct, then you need only to count the command line argument array size, and look at the odd number arguments and deal with the next arguments if the previous argument is a one of interest. I wouldn't worry about elegance at this stage of the game. I'd worry more about "functionality".

Comment: One problem you might be having is that you find arguments i and i+1.  Then you incement i by 1.  You might need to increment i by 2.

Comment: The Apache cli libray does look to be quite useful. Have you tried playing with it some? It looks like all you'd need to do would be to add two Option objects to an Options object, and then call `parse(...)` passing in the Options object and your command line. Then it would be an easy business extracting the Strings you need from the CommandLine object returned. Shoot, I may have to download this library as it looks quite easy and useful. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I think I'll try to do that with the Apache CLI... Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Example code can be found [here](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = findArg("input", args);
    String output = findArg("output", args);
}

static String findArg(String name, String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
        if (args[i].equals("-" + name)) {
            return args[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your logic; and that is why it doesnt work. If I run the program with the following arguments `java classname -input input.txt -output output.txt` then your code will take input from terminal and output to the output.txt.

Update - actually it will crash with NullPointerException